# Nifi Basic Auth implementation

Tags: security, apache-nifi

### Objective

Nifi `ListenHTTP`/`HandleHTTPRequest` processors don't support Basic Auth, so as it was suggested by [this answer](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/HandleHttpRequest-Client-Authentication-configuration/m-p/164724/highlight/true#M127091) - you can use `ListenHTTP`/`HandleHTTPRequest` processors with RouteOnAttribute to validate username & password. In my case, Nifi accepts plain HTTP request because Nifi is hidden under Api Gateway SSL termination. If to be precise, Nifi gets HTTP Authorization header, which due to [Basic Auth Client Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) equals to `base64(username + ':' + password)`

### Question

*Does it make sense to store credentials on Nifi side as sensitive parameters, if Nifi got Authorization HTTP header in plain text?*

If yes, *how can I securely validate HTTP request credentials against expected pair?*

If no, *is there any other secure way to store password on Nifi side and implement Basic Auth?*

### The issue

I have to store expected username-password pair inside Parameter Context sensitive parameters. That means I can't reach those parameters from `UpdateAttribute` or `RouteOnAttribute` processors = I don't know how to validate/authorize request.

Comment: If you have API gateway then why don't you implement authentication on the level of gateway? Otherwise the simplest way to validate http header (attribute) is script. Storage could be literally anything.

Comment: @daggett adding another storage and trying to implement sensitive properties by my own looks like overkill. Does Azure Api Gateway support Basic Auth?

Comment: Never used az-apim, but this sounds promising: https://aztoso.com/posts/apim-basic-auth-keyvault/

Comment: How many users  do you have for your API?

Comment: @daggett 1 user - orchestration tool

Answer (score 0):

When you send a request to the `HandleHttpRequest` processor with Basic Auth, you have an access to the `http.headers.Authorization` attribute. It looks like `Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=` for `username:password`.
So you can use `RouteOnAttribute` if this value matches your credentials or not. You can also fetch the value from a database for comparing.
You should evaluate the value before the `HandleHttpResponse` processor.

Comment: For security you can add a sensitive parameter to `Parameter Contexts`